# how to control execute IP with startup.sh script when deploy nodejs(express) app in the same server?

Tags: node.js, bash, express, deployment, pm2

I'm trying deploy a simple front project.

There is another server for api server, so all I need is just simple build file of front project and run it on the nodejs server.

I configure the nodejs with the express generator which has the basic features.

After setting up the nodejs, the below command has been set to run my project in the `startup.sh` script on the server.

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

The **ecosystem.config.js** file contains the following

```js
app:[
  {
   name: "my-app",
   script: "./bin/www",
   instances: "1",
   env_production: {
     NODE_ENV: "production",
   },
  }
]
```

**/startup.sh**  (in a brief version)

```bash
pm2 list

# npm install
npm install
kill $PID
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
pm2 save
```

However, in order to prevent conflicts with other projects already running in the server, I need to change the execution ip any time.

Normally, I would have specified ip and port values in the `/bin/www` file  and app.js will be running by `server.listen(port, ip)`

But what I trying to do is, if the ip value is specified in the `startup.sh` script, it should be changed in `/bin/www` too.

I also looked up about pm2 deploy, but in the case of pm2 deploy, there is a host designation, but the solution seems to be meaningless because it is not the way to execute my project by git pull. I use s3 bucket and upload my project from local and then download in the server using scripts(`startup.sh` or `update.sh`).

**Long question short**

If you specify an ip value in the startup.sh script, can I use pm2 to change the ip on the nodejs server and run the program? or is there another way to designate ip value in the script to run nodejs server??

thanks for the help in advance